# Не запускается Google Chrome из-под supervisor'а

Tags: linux, ubuntu, google-chrome, chromedriver, supervisord

Мне нужно запустить Google Chrome из-под `supervisor`.

Мой конфиг:

```
[program:chrome]
command=google-chrome
user=w3lifer
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stderr_logfile=/var/log/supervisor/chrome.err.log
stdout_logfile=/var/log/supervisor/chrome.out.log
environment=DISPLAY=:0
```

Процесс запускается:

[image]

Однако **сам браузер нет**!

В `/var/log/supervisor/chrome.err.log`:

```sh
chrome_crashpad_handler: --database is required
Try 'chrome_crashpad_handler --help' for more information.
```

Пробовал запускать с разными флагами:

- `--profile-directory=/home/<user>/.config/google-chrome/Default`
- `--no-sandbox`
- `--disable-gpu --disable-software-rasterizer`
- `--crash-handler`
- `--crash-dumps-dir=/tmp/crash-dumps-dir`

Не помогло.

---

Нашёл похожие вопросы, но пустышки:

- https://stackoverflow.com/q/31658148/4223982
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/23752238/4223982
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/35041574/4223982

---

Попробовал запустить Firefox:

```
[program:firefox]
command=firefox
user=w3lifer
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stderr_logfile=/var/log/supervisor/firefox.err.log
stdout_logfile=/var/log/supervisor/firefox.out.log
environment=DISPLAY=:0
```

Всё отлично!

---

Собственно, вопрос видимо с `chrome_crashpad_handler: --database is required`. Но как это решить пока не знаю ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я запускаю новый экземпляр супервизора как сервис пользователя в окружении сессии пользователя. А в нем уже всё стартует без проблем.

Comment: Да, собственно, я перезагрузил комп и всё заработало :) с текущей реализацией. От всех бед — один ресет ...